# AWS ElasticBeanstalk .ebextensions not being executed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I am trying to get a few things completed post deploy on AWS EB.  I have added my `.ebextensions` to the git repository and I only have one file `01_container_commands.config`, it does not appear to run when I tail the `/var/log/eb-activity.log`  At one point it was running and was failing on command 05 listed below so I removed 05 but now it does not run at all.

```
container_commands:
  01_user_permission:
    command: /usr/sbin/usermod -a -G webapp ec2-user
  02_remove_storage_directory:
    command: rm -rf /var/app/current/storage
  03_create_storage_directories:
    command: mkdir /var/app/current/storage /var/app/current/storage/framework /var/app/current/storage/framework/session /var/app/current/storage/framework/views /var/app/current/storage/framework/cache
  04_set_storage_permissions:
    command: chmod -fR 755 /var/app/current/storage
  05_copy_env_file
    command: cp /var/app/current/.aws.env /var/app/current/.env
```

It would appear that it is not running my ebextensions, any ideas what I could check to find out why?

As a side note I have tried wrapping my commands with double quotes, that didn't seem to help either.

As you can see below it's just not executing my script at all.

```
[2017-01-09T19:59:09.615Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_update_permissions.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:20.431Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_update_permissions.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user
  + EB_APP_USER=webapp
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_base_dir
  + EB_APP_BASE_DIR=/var/app
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_logs_dir
  + EB_APP_LOGS_DIR=/var/app/support/logs
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + chown -R webapp:webapp /var/app
  + chown -R webapp:webapp /var/log/httpd
  + '[' -f app/SymfonyRequirements.php ']'
[2017-01-09T19:59:20.431Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre.
[2017-01-09T19:59:20.432Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.040Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.040Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.075Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.076Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage0/InfraCleanEbextension] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.157Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage0/InfraCleanEbextension] : Completed activity. Result:
  Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from /var/app/ondeck.
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.157Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage0] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy stage 0 completed
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.158Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.158Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.158Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01_flip.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.535Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01_flip.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=/var/app/current
  + '[' -d /var/app/current ']'
  + mv /var/app/current /var/app/current.old
  + mv /var/app/ondeck /var/app/current
  + nohup rm -rf /var/app/current.old
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.535Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/99_reload_app_server.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.677Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/99_reload_app_server.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Equivalent Upstart operations: start httpd, stop httpd, restart httpd, status httpd
  Gracefully restarting httpd
  [OK]
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.677Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact.
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.678Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:21.678Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/01_monitor_httpd_pid.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.168Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/01_monitor_httpd_pid.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  + chmod 0755 /var/run/httpd
  + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy httpd
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.168Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post.
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.169Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AppDeployStage1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application version switch - Command CMD-AppDeploy stage 1 completed
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.169Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.169Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.170Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.611Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] :     Completed activity. Result:
  Disabled forced hourly log rotation.
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.612Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logpublish/hooks/config.
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.612Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.613Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.923Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Log streaming option setting is not specified, ignore cloudwatch logs setup.

  Disabled log streaming.
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.923Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logstreaming/hooks/config.
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.923Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2017-01-09T19:59:22.924Z] INFO  [26612] - [Application update app-fb58-170109_145741@53] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy succeeded
```

Comment: How are you deploying it to EB?

Comment: I am using the CLI Tools ```eb deploy```, the deployment works fine however the config file is only executed sometimes and not all the time with every deploy.  More recently it appears to have just stopped executing all together.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands), your commands should be double-quoted, like below. You were also missing a colon after `05_copy_env_file`.

I know you said you tried double-quoting, but can you retry after fixing both the quoting and the colon? Also please update your question with your new `01_container_commands.config` file and the entire `/var/log/eb-activity.log` file. Thanks!

```
container_commands:
  01_user_permission:
    command: "/usr/sbin/usermod -a -G webapp ec2-user"
  02_remove_storage_directory:
    command: "rm -rf /var/app/current/storage"
  03_create_storage_directories:
    command: "mkdir /var/app/current/storage /var/app/current/storage/framework /var/app/current/storage/framework/session /var/app/current/storage/framework/views /var/app/current/storage/framework/cache"
  04_set_storage_permissions:
    command: "chmod -fR 755 /var/app/current/storage"
  05_copy_env_file:
    command: "cp /var/app/current/.aws.env /var/app/current/.env"
```

Comment: I had tried with and without quotes.. That was not the problem, even after fixing those it was not working.  The reason is because I needed to do this stuff "post-deployment" which is not really documented, this article is what made things start to work for me.

http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/

Comment: Good to hear you got it working! I wish AWS would officially support the "post-deployment" technique, but as you found it works just fine.

That being said, your `01_user_permission` step should run just fine as a regular `container_command` since it's not affecting `/var/app/current`.

Comment: Just in case someone else stumbles upon this and is wondering why their `.platform` or `.ebextensions` dir is not working even after following every doc properly, make sure you have the `Procfile`, `.ebextensions/**/*` and `.platform/**/*` in the `files` list of `artifacts` directive in your `buildspec.yml` file.

Comment: @DevangMistry Note: You only need buildspec.yml if you're using AWS CodeBuild.